# How to get checkout cart URL on checkout page in shipping.html template file?

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkout-page

I want to add an anchor link as "Return to Cart" just beside "Next" button on checkout page shipping address form. I have added an anchor tag in

> app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

file just above the Next button.

What I want to know is how to get checkout cart URL in href to redirect to cart page on clicking anchor tag?

Code is something like below,

```
<div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
    <div class="primary">
        <a class="checkout-return-cart" href="#"><span translate="'Return to cart'" /></a>
        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
              <span translate="'Next'" />
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have got the solution.
It is very simple like javascript variable `window.checkoutConfig` contains many other variables and checkout details.

To get checkout cart URL, use `window.checkoutConfig.cartUrl` to get cart URL.

I have updated my code as below and it worked!

```
<div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
     <div class="primary">
          <a class="checkout-return-cart" href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: window.checkoutConfig.cartUrl }"><span translate="'Return to cart'" /></a>
               <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                     <span translate="'Next'" />
               </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to use this solution in Magento 2, using the code here, less the next button as I just needed a way to have a link to the cart in another knockoutjs template .html file in the checkout. Thank you!